# Prove whether or not $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have the following function:
$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0) = 0$. Now I want to proof that $f$ is differentiable in $(0,0)$, but I get stuck with an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof for the limit
\begin{equation}
\lim_{(k,h) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(0+k,0+h) - f(0,0) - kf_1(0,0) - hf_2(0,0)}{\sqrt{k^2 + h^2}} = 0
\end{equation}
I think that $f_1(0,0) = f_2(0,0) = 0$, because $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h,0) - f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{h^2 \cdot 0}{h^2 + 0}-0}{h} = 0$. And the same for $y+h$.

So the actual limit I want to solve is
\begin{equation}
\lim_{(k,h) \to (0,0)} \frac{\frac{k^2h}{k^2+h^2}}{\sqrt{k^2+h^2}} = \lim_{(k,h) \to (0,0)} \frac{k^2h}{(k^2 + h^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = 0
\end{equation}
Perhaps I made a mistake earlier on, but I can't seem to give a right proof of the existence of the limit...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $f$ is *not* differentiable at $(0,0)$. If it was, then, since $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=0$, then $f'(0,0)$ would be the null function. In other words,$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=0.$$But if $x=y>0$, $\frac{x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=\frac1{2\sqrt2}$.